# Prevent __init__ from being called after __new__?

Tags: python, constructor, initialization, super

Here's my code which I use to create "cached" instances:

```
class Foo(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, index):
        if index in cls._instances:
            return cls._instances[index]
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        cls._instances[index] = instance
        return instance

    def __init__(self, index):
        print('__init__: {0}'.format(index))
```

The problem appears when I already have an instance of the same index; it should do nothing except return the existing instance, but it also invokes `__init__` on the new instance:

```
>>> f = Foo(1)
__init__: 1
>>> f.x = True
>>> b = Foo(1)
__init__: 1
>>> b.x
True
```

The problem is `b = Foo(1)` also prints `__init__: 1` when it "shouldn't" (I don't want it to).
Is there a way to prevent the`__init__` from being called in such cases?

Comment: Why use `__init__` *at all*? You already have a `__new__` method.. just do the initialisation there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My professor said you should customize `__new__` when you're modifying how the instance is created, and use `__init__` for everything else, including initialization of its attributes... Would I be better off not using `__init__` here? **Edit:** Okay thanks... I'll just use `__new__` instead

Comment: `__init__`, if defined, is executed on *whatever `__new__` returns*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but just to be precise, `__init__` is looked up on the value returned from `__new__`; it doesn't necessarily use `__init__` from the same class where `__new__` was defined. Of course, returning something from `__new__` that's of a different type from the current class is rather naughty.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel good point well made